# Are my answers to this hypothesis question correct?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

Here is the full question:

The fill of a cereal box machine is required to 18 ounces, with the variance already established at 0.24. The past 150 boxes revealed an average of 17.96 ounces. A testing error of α = 2% is considered acceptable. If the box overfills, profits are lost; if the box underfills, the consumer is cheated.
(a) Can we conclude that machine is set at 18 ounces?
(b) Find a 98% confidence interval for μ.
(c) Would the result change if the sample variance were 0.24 from the data rather than knowing $σ^2$ = 0.24?

**My Answer:**

(a) 
I calculated the positive square root of the variance (0.24) to get the standard deviation of the population - σ = 0.49. I found the acceptable region to be between -2.33 and 2.33, so, for a value of z = -0.9998, I concluded that the machine **is** set at 18 ounces.

(b) 
17.87 < μ < 18.05

(c) 
I understood the question as: "will there be a change in the result of part (b) if 0.24 changed from being a **population variance** to a **sample variance**". My answer is that when only the standard deviation of a sample is known and **n>30**, the same formula will be used to calculate the 98% confidence interval, so there will be no change in the result of part (b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts (a) and (b) are correct. (Although for part (a) one might quibble that we are not accepting that the machine pours an average of $18$ ounces, rather failing to reject that it does. In any event this quibble is for whoever wrote the problem, not you.)

Part (c) is right in the sense that for a sample size as large as $150,$ using a normal distribution rather than a t distribution doesn't change the answer significantly. There is a theoretical difference though.

Comment: So, technically, my answer to part c is correct?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a valid answer and probably what they are looking for. I was just saying it kind of depends on the definition of the word "change".